# C# references inside method with lambdas

Tags: c#, events

Okay so here is the deal. Imagine that I have a method that is setup to pragmatically build some buttons. This method has an EventHandler inside it for the button clicks, that has a lambda function attached to it. All the input data is defined on the method. Such as what setting we are adjusting. The lambda sets the value from the method. As seen in the code snip I have provided.

```
void BuildSetting<T>( T SettingValue, string SettingName ){
   Control x = new Control();
   x.onClicked += (){
      SettingValue.Text = "new text"; // doesnt work because SettingValue is not a reference
   }
}
```

Okay now here is my problem. Normally I would add the 'ref' keyword in front of SettingValue in the method properties. Such as seen below to change the settings on the referenced object

```
void BuildSetting<T>( ref T SettingValue, string SettingName ){ }
```

I cannot do that in this case because of the lambda function breaking the ref keyword with error CS1628. I would like to return an event handler from BuildSettings so when the lambda fires it will fire off the BuildSetting() caller but is that possible in c#. Something like

```
EventHandler BuildSettings<T>( T SettingValue, string SettingName ) {
   EventHandler eh = new EventHandler();
   Control x = new Control();
   x.onClicked += () => {
      eh?.Invoke("new text");
   }
   return eh;
}
```

Along with this for actually performing responses

```
BuildSettings( ControlObject, "Display Resolution" ) += (string str){ ControlObject.Text = str; };
```

I feel like this would be as easy as passing in a void* in c but very difficult in c#.

---

Or if anyone has a better idea to get the lambda result back into the referenced object I would greatly appreciate it and thank you.

Comment: You could use an Action<T> delegate, also in the form of an event. See the notes here: [Passing C# function in constructor to be used as a subscriber to EventHandler delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77589228/7444103)

Comment: What is `T`? You said _"SettingValue is not a reference"_, so `T` should be a value type. But obviously `T` has a `Text` property, so `T`'s declaration must have a constraint. Then what is the constraint declaration? It must be some concrete value type like `where T : SettingValue`, but in C#, a value type cannot be used as constraint, so there's a fundamental error in your question.

Comment: BTW, if you only want to use the methods contained in `struct`, such as `ToString`, then lambdas can work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/r1dJ9k

Comment: The Action<T> worked but I had to create the event and pass it into the function. Your awesome Jimi